# What does the condition lever in turboprops control?

Tags: turboprop

Turbojet and turbofan engines have just one control lever that controls the thrust by setting the amount of fuel injected.

But most turboprop aircraft have *three* levers. One adjusts the fuel flow, one adjusts the propeller speed, but what does the third one do? Does it only act as an on-off switch as simulators tend to present it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shamelessly quoting from [Skybrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Condition_Lever): (emphasys mine)

> A Condition Lever is a pilot actuated control which is located within
>   the throttle quadrant of a turboprop engine equipped aircraft. It is
>   utilised to control some functions of both the propeller and the
>   engine. **These functions vary from installation to installation.**
>
> Functions of the condition lever can include any of the following:
>
> - Fuel cut-off.
> - Propeller feathering.
> - Propeller un-feathering.
> - Low idle/high idle selection.
> - Propeller speed control.

Comment: More details from [Avcanada](http://www.avcanada.ca/forums2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=49644).